# How to stop MongoDB Database Server to run automatically on windows startup?

Tags: windows, mongodb

Every time I start up my pc, the MongoDB database Server automatically starts up on the background by itself.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gi4Im.png

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/4026268/windows-10-change-startup-apps

Comment: @Nelles, this may disable an application to start (there are many other possibilities apart from the "Startup" folder. However, MongoDB runs as a service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Every time I start up my pc, the MongoDB database Server automatically
>   starts up on the background by itself.

This is because you have installed MongoDB as a Windows service.

You can [Stop MongoDB Community Edition as a Windows Service](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/index.html#stop-mongodb-community-edition-as-a-windows-service). But, this will be for this session only; and again when you start your PC MongoDB will start again.

You can [Remove MongoDB Community Edition as a Windows Service](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/index.html#remove-mongodb-community-edition-as-a-windows-service). This will not start the MongoDB when you start the PC. Then [you must manually start the MongoDB instance.](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/index.html#if-you-did-not-install-mongodb-as-a-windows-service).

Answer (score 0):

First stop the service, then you can disable or remove it.

Stop the service: `net stop MongoDB`

Disable the service: `sc config MongoDB start=disabled`

Remove the service: `mongod.exe --config <MongoDB configuration file> --remove` or `sc.exe delete MongoDB`

Or you can do all these steps also with your mouse in the Services console.